# Executorservice workers are not running in separate threads

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, threadpool, executorservice

I am using newFixedThreadPool to simultaneously serve incoming requests to a server socket. For some reason the worker classes serving the clients are not being run in separate threads. When I send multiple requests to the socket, the requests get served sequentially, not simultaneously like they should. I am running OpenJDK 1.8.0_77 if that makes any difference.

This is an excerpt of my main class:

```
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100);
    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(5656);

    while(true) {
        Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
        executorService.execute(new ConnectionHandler(socket));
    }
```

This is my worker class:

```
    public class ConnectionHandler implements Runnable {

    private Socket socket;

    public ConnectionHandler(Socket socket) {
        this.socket = socket;
    }

    public void run() {

        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        BufferedReader reader = null;
        PrintWriter writer = null;
        try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        writer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

        while(true) {
            String line = reader.readLine();
            if(line == null) break;
            writer.println("Echo: " + line);
        }
        } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } finally {
        try {
            if(reader != null) reader.close();
            if(writer != null) writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        }
    }

    }
```

Comment: How do you know it isn't using different threads? Log the thread name to be sure.

Comment: Are you sure this is not  a problem of your test client?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I not good with computer.

The problem was that I was echoing many messages in a loop to the socket, but the echo command sends messages sequentially and waits for every message to finish before it sends the next one.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this call:

```
executorService.execute(new ConnectionHandler(socket));
```

The `execute` method is allowed to force the calling thread to block until the task is complete, or even have the calling thread perform the actual work. Instead, do this:

```
executorService.submit(new ConnectionHandler(socket));
```

This will asynchronously run your task using threads in the pool.

Comment: I have a hard time believing this. The example code in the API doc for ExecutorService uses execute.

Comment: Read the javadoc here - it says the calling thread may be used to perform the work:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html#execute%28java.lang.Runnable%29

Comment: @NathanHughes is right - the two method differ in signature only, not in their behavior with regard to threading. An executor created with "newFixedThreadPool" will distribute tasks to different threads

Comment: I understand that different implementations of `execute` have the freedom to do so asynchronously, but I would be hesitant to use any interface that allows behavior contrary to what's needed.  Worst-case, the implementation allows the calling thread to do the work, as stated by the spec. The `submit` method spec strongly implies asynchronous execution by stating that tasks are scheduled for execution later, while `execute` merely says it's possible but not always the case.  The Oracle JVM might implement it asynchronously but the OpenJDK or any other JVM vendor may not. Why leave it to chance?

Comment: But as you not only consume the interface but create the implementation, you *know* what the execution strategy is. Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100) is bound to create a multi-threaded Executor on any implementation.